# Update data frame values as per multiple where condition using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I want to change `DateWork['Variable']` values as per multiple where conditions and update in  `DateWork['Date']`

If `Frequency=3` and `len(Variable)=6` then replace M with "-0" and update in `DateWork['Date']`
If `Frequency=3` and `len(Variable)=7` then replace M with "-" and update in `DateWork['Date']`

DataFrame: DateWork

```
Frequency Variable      Date
3         1950M2        1950-02-01
3         1950M3        1950-03-01
2         1950-07-01    1950-07-01
3         1950M9        1950-09-01
2         1950-10-01    1950-10-01
3         1950M10       1950-10-01
```

My code:

```
DateWork.loc[DateWork['Date']] = np.where(((DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['variable'].str.len() == 6)), 'M', '-0',  DateWork['Date'])
DateWork.loc[DateWork['Date']] = np.where(((DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['variable'].str.len() == 7)), 'M', '-',  DateWork['Date'])
DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 3, 'Date'] = DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 3, 'variable'] + '-01'
```

This gives error:

> TypeError: where() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is raised because you were passing one extra argument to `np.where`, you can check the documentation about this method, link is below. also once, this problem gets fixed, the way you wrote your code makes the last `np.where` call update and replace all the ones before, so they need to be "nested" in order to work properly.

I also provided a solution without `np.where` should you request it.

Solution with [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
# where frequenct == 3 and len(variable) == 6, we put variable and replace M with -0, if that's not
# the case, we search where frequency == 3 and len(variable) == 7 and put variable while replacing M with -
# else we just put Variable
DateWork['Date'] = np.where((DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['Variable'].str.len() == 6), DateWork['Variable'].str.replace('M','-0'),
                       np.where((DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['Variable'].str.len() == 7), DateWork['Variable'].str.replace('M','-'), DateWork['Variable']))

# we add first day date where frequency == 3
DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 3, 'Date'] = DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 3, 'Date'] + '-01'
```

Solution with [pandas.dataframe.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
# where frenquency == 3 and len(variable) == 6, in date we put variable and replace M with -0
DateWork.loc[(DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['Variable'].str.len() == 6),'Date'] = DateWork['Variable'].str.replace('M','-0')

# where frequency == 3 and len(variable) == 7, in date we put variable and replace M with -
DateWork.loc[(DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['Variable'].str.len() == 7),'Date'] = DateWork['Variable'].str.replace('M','-')

# where frequency == 2, in date we simply put variable
DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 2,'Date'] = DateWork['Variable']

# where frequency == 3, in date we add first day date.
DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 3, 'Date'] = DateWork.loc[DateWork['Frequency'] == 3, 'Date'] + '-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If nesting `np.where` is hard to read,

```
DateWork
Out[32]: 
   Frequency    Variable        Date
0          3      1950M2  1950-02-01
1          3      1950M3  1950-03-01
2          2  1950-07-01  1950-07-01
3          3      1950M9  1950-09-01
4          2  1950-10-01  1950-10-01
5          3     1950M10  1950-10-01
```

First if:

The else condition is the original `Date` column itself

```
DateWork['Date'] = np.where((DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['Variable'].str.len() == 6), DateWork['Variable'].str.replace('M','-0'), DateWork['Date'])

DateWork
Out[34]: 
   Frequency    Variable        Date
0          3      1950M2     1950-02
1          3      1950M3     1950-03
2          2  1950-07-01  1950-07-01
3          3      1950M9     1950-09
4          2  1950-10-01  1950-10-01
5          3     1950M10  1950-10-01
```

Second If:

Here, the else condition is the output `date` column of the above step

```
DateWork['Date'] = np.where((DateWork['Frequency'] == 3) & (DateWork['Variable'].str.len() == 7), DateWork['Variable'].str.replace('M','-'), DateWork['Date'])

DateWork
Out[36]: 
   Frequency    Variable        Date
0          3      1950M2     1950-02
1          3      1950M3     1950-03
2          2  1950-07-01  1950-07-01
3          3      1950M9     1950-09
4          2  1950-10-01  1950-10-01
5          3     1950M10     1950-10
```