# How to replace multiple values in np.where?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

IF “AUTHORITY_CONTACTED” is NOT “Police” and POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE == 1

THEN Update “AUTHORITY_CONTACTED” to Police.

The unique values for [AUTHORITY_CONTACTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYNsU.png) are Ambulance, Police, None, and Others and POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE is a column that has 0 and 1 as its unique values which tells if the document is available if the AUTHORITY_CONTACTED is police.

Below is my code on the above query which was taken from [Update data frame values as per multiple where condition using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995737/update-data-frame-values-as-per-multiple-where-condition-using-numpy)

```
dataset['AUTHORITY_CONTACTED'] = np.where((dataset['AUTHORITY_CONTACTED'] != 'Police') & (dataset['POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE'] == 1), dataset['AUTHORITY_CONTACTED'].replace('Ambulance', 'Police'), dataset['POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE'])
```

1. How can I replace multiple values in a where?
2. After I run the code for the above query dataset['AUTHORITY_CONTACTED'] column is filled with 1 rather than replacing Ambulance with Police

Given dataset:

| AUTHORITY_CONTACTED | POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE |
| --- | --- |
| Police | 1 |
| Ambulance | 0 |
| None | 0 |
| Others | 1 |
| Ambulance | 1 |

Expected Output:

| AUTHORITY_CONTACTED | POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE |
| --- | --- |
| Police | 1 |
| Ambulance | 0 |
| None | 0 |
| Police | 1 |
| Police | 1 |

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: can you show a sample of `dataset['AUTHORITY_CONTACTED']`

Comment: I've added a link for the image pls check

Comment: please post the expected output. Avoid images since we can't copy and paste the df for testing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# Using np.where
dataset["AUTHORITY_CONTACTED"] = np.where(
    dataset["AUTHORITY_CONTACTED"].ne("Police") & dataset["POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE"].eq(1),
    "Police",
    dataset["AUTHORITY_CONTACTED"]
)

# Slightly shorter code using pd.Series.mask
dataset["AUTHORITY_CONTACTED"] = dataset["AUTHORITY_CONTACTED"].mask(
    dataset["AUTHORITY_CONTACTED"].ne("Police") & dataset["POLICE_REPORT_AVAILABLE"].eq(1),
    "Police"
)
```